Can the "three laws of thought" be used as alternative axioms of the sentential calculus?
I'm reading a little book on formal systems. After introducing truth tables, the book formulates the sentential calculus as a formal axiomatic theory in which the symbols are $\rightarrow$,$\neg$, $($, $)$, and the sentential letters $A_1, A_2, \dots $. The well formed formulas (wff) are defined recursively, and the Axiom schemes are:
$$L1: \ (A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow A))     $$
$$L2: \ ((A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow C)) \rightarrow ((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow (A\rightarrow C)))          $$
$$L3: \ ((( \neg B) \rightarrow(\neg A)) \rightarrow (((\neg B) \rightarrow A)\rightarrow B)) $$
For $A,B,C$ any wff. The book than defines conjunction and disjunction as
$$  A \wedge  B =  \neg(A\rightarrow \neg B)  $$
$$ A\vee B = (\neg A)\rightarrow B  $$
I'm using the symbol "$=$" above meta-linguisticaly. The only inference rule is modus ponens.
I was rather surprised by these axioms because they don't really make much intuitive sense to me. I would have guessed that the axioms would involve the so called "three traditional laws of thought", identity ($ A\rightarrow A$), non contradiction ($\neg(A\wedge \neg A)$) , and the excluded middle ($ \ A \vee \neg A$). The book then goes on to use these axioms to prove the theorem $A\rightarrow A$, and later discusses how every tautology is a theorem of this system. Well, the aforementioned three laws are tautologies, so they must be theorems. My question is, can we replace the three axioms above by
$$L1*: \ A\rightarrow A  $$
$$ L2*: \ \neg(A\wedge \neg A) $$
$$L3*: \ A \vee \neg A$$
and obtain as theorems all the same theorems as those obtained with the original $L1,L2,L3$?

$\lnot$ is not in your language. It is defined?

Personally, I found L1 and L2 unintelligible until I learnt about the lambda calculus, and the S and K combinators, and the theorem stating that any closed lambda term can be written using S and K alone. YMMV

@ThomasAndrews yes, I forgot to about the negation sign, it's also one of the symbols.

Don't tell me, edit your question.

No, we cannot replace the three axioms above with the traditional laws of thought. Even if we define $A \wedge B$ as $\neg (A \rightarrow \neg B)$, $A \vee B$ as $(\neg A) \rightarrow B$, the three traditional laws of thought are not at all sufficient as a basis formal logic.
Expanding out the definitions, the laws of thought look as follows:

L1★: $x \rightarrow x$
L2★: $\neg\neg(x \rightarrow \neg\neg x)$
L3★: $\neg x \rightarrow \neg x$

Interpret the connectives $\rightarrow$ and $\neg$ in a heterodox way, as follows:

Let $x \rightarrow y$ mean that $x$ and $y$ have the same truth value (are both true or both false).
Let $\neg x$ mean that $x$ is not true (this is the same as the usual reading).

The three traditional laws hold true not just under the usual interpretation of the connectives, but under this heterodox interpretation as well. L1★ just means that $x$ always has the same truth value as $x$ itself, which is true. Double-negation is still affirmation, so L2★ reduces to $x \rightarrow x$ (L1★), which holds again. Similarly for L3★.
Moreover, if $x$ holds true under this heterodox interpretation, and $x \rightarrow y$ holds true as well, then $y$ must have the same truth value as $x$, so $y$ itself must hold true under the heterodox reading. This means that the inference rule, Modus Ponens, remains valid when we read the connectives in this heterodox manner.
Now, L1 clearly follows from modus ponens and the original L1,L2,L3. But does L1 follow from L1★, L2★, L3★? If it did, then $x \rightarrow (y \rightarrow x)$ would have to hold true under this heterodox interpretation no matter what truth value $x$ and $y$ have.
But that's not the case. If $x$ and $y$ are both false, then $x$ and $y$ have the same truth value, so under our heterodox interpretation $y \rightarrow x$ is true. But $x \rightarrow (y \rightarrow x)$ asserts that $x$ and $y \rightarrow x$ should have the same truth value. Instead, $x$ is false and $y \rightarrow x$ is true.
So $x \rightarrow (y \rightarrow x)$ does not hold under this heterodox interpretation, and thus cannot be derived if we take the three traditional laws of thought as our only axioms.
To summarize: if $x \rightarrow (y \rightarrow x)$ would follow from the starred axioms, then it would be true for any connective which satisfies those axioms. But we've found a connective (the heterodox reading of $\rightarrow$ above) which satisfies all three starred axioms, but does not satisfy the desired conclusion. So the desired conclusion does not follow from the starred axioms.
